# Bubble IOException from PipedOutputStream to PipedInputStream

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, inputstream, outputstream

I am writing some data to a `PipedOutputStream` which I have connected to a `PipedInputStream` that I pass along to some third party API.
Writing to the PipedOutputStream is done asynchronously, on another thread.

When an `IOException` is thrown by the PipedOutputStream, what is the effect on the corresponding PipedInputStream? Does it also throw an exception? I would think this is the desired behaviour because the content that the InputStream should provide is not complete.

If this is not the case, how can I simulate this effect?

Note: The PipedOutputStream is wrapped in the try-with-resources statement which autocloses the OutputStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get IOException on PipedOutputStream only in case you close connected PipedInputStream. Which means that at that time you cannot read from input anymore. There is no way how you could deliver artificial IOException.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) is not clear on this. It says `write` throws an _IOException - if the pipe is broken, unconnected, closed, **or if an I/O error occurs**._ This last part makes me think I have to protect myself.